Is it possible to have different splash screens between prod and dev in react native
I'm a beginner with React Native. I know maybe this is kinda foolish question but I'm not sure if it's possible to have different splash screens between prod and dev in react native.
I tried to add LaunchScreen and Images for dev in the XCode and it works for the Develop mode, but it makes side effect in the Production mode so the Production mode didn't work properly.


Yes, it is possible to have different splash screens between prod and dev in React Native. You can achieve this by using conditional rendering based on the environment.

First, you need to set up different environments for your project. You can do this by creating a .env file in the root of your project and defining your environment variables.
//This is for development
.env
REACT_NATIVE_ENV = dev

//This is for production
.env
REACT_NATIVE_ENV = prod


Then, you need to install react-native-config to access these environment variables in your code.
npm install react-native-config
          or
yarn add react-native-config


After installing react-native-config, you can access your environment variables in your code like this,
 import config from 'react-native-config';

 if (config.REACT_NATIVE_ENV === 'dev') {
   // Show dev splash screen
 } else {
   // Show prod splash screen
 }


Now, you can create two different splash screens (one for dev and one for prod) and show them based on the environment.
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import DevSplashScreen from './DevSplashScreen';
import ProdSplashScreen from './ProdSplashScreen';
import config from 'react-native-config';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

  if (config.REACT_NATIVE_ENV === 'dev') {
     return <DevSplashScreen />;
  } else {
     return <ProdSplashScreen />;
  }
};

export default App;



